# Actualizar primary key desde php

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito actualizar todos los campos de una tabla desde un formulario, incluida su clave primaria(dni) si fuese necesario, para eso cargo los valores que quiero modificar y por medio de un POST modifico los valores en la BD, el caso es que no se como hacer para actualizar la clave primaria, los otros campos los actualizo sin problema, no hay ningún conflicto de consistencia ya que ninguna clave se esta utilizando en otra tabla...

```
  <?php

     include 'conexionPDO.php';

      if (!isset($_POST['bot_actualizar'])) { 
      //cargo los datos que se modificaran obtenidos de otra tabla
         $dni=$_GET['dni'];           //ESTA ES LA PRIMARY KEY OBTENIDO DE OTRA TABLA
         $apellido=$_GET['ape'];
         $tipoUsuario=$_GET['usu'];

       }else{
      //valores que se actualizarán   
         $id=$_POST['dni'];   
         $apellido=$_POST['ape'];
         $tipoUsuario=$_POST['usu'];
```

AQUI ESTA EL ERROR:

```
        $sql="UPDATE usuario SET dni=:miDNI, apellido=:miApellido, tipo_usuario=:miUsuario WHERE 
         usuario.dni=:miDNI";    // -------> AQUI DEBERIA IR LA CLAVE QUE SE DESEA MODIFICAR
        $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
        $resultado->execute(array(":miDNI"=>$id, ":miApellido"=>$apellido, 
        ":miUsuario"=>$tipoUsuario, ":DNI"=>$dni));

         header("Location:form_admin.php");
  }
```

?>

```
     <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
      <fieldset><legend>Modificar Usuario</legend>
       <table width="25%" border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
         <td>DNI</td>
         <td><label for="dni"></label>
         <input type="text" name="dni" id="id" value="<?php echo $dni?>"></td>      

      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Apellido</td>
         <td><label for="nom"></label>
         <input type="text" name="ape" id="ape" value="<?php echo $apellido?>"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Usuario</td>
         <td><label for="ape"></label>
         <input type="text" name="usu" id="usu" value="<?php echo $tipoUsuario?>"></td>
     </tr>   
     <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="bot_actualizar" value="Actualizar"> 
    </td>
    </tr></fieldset>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué esperas las variables por get o post?

Comment: Las claves primarias no deberían ser actualizables, eso es una mala practica

Comment: Estás asignando el mismo marcador en dos lugares: `UPDATE usuario SET dni=:miDNI ... WHERE dni=:miDNI`, creo que este último debería ser solo `dni=:DNI`, pero todavía falta ver si estás obteniendo tanto DNI original como actualizado.

Comment: Si bien, es técnicamente posible actualizar PKs, no es recomendable. Puede ser muy caro actualizar todas las referencias que otras tablas tengan hace ésta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dice @JhonMaldonado, las PK no deberían cambiar. Además en tu `UPDATE` estarías seteando el mismo DNI que ya existe, ¿qué sentido tiene eso?

Por otro lado, no necesitas pasar estos datos en el `execute()`: **`":DNI"=>$dni`**, la consulta preparada no tiene un paŕámetro llamado `:DNI`. Si necesitaras dos parámetros y el mismo dato sí podrías pasar `$dni` asociado a dos parámteros, pero **ambos deberían existir en la consulta preparada**, de lo contrario PDO no sabrá en qué parte de la consulta asociar el dato. Ese es el sentido de los marcadores en las consultas preparadas.

Tu consulta debería escribirse así simplemente:

```
    $sql="UPDATE usuario SET apellido=:miApellido, tipo_usuario=:miUsuario
                 WHERE dni=:miDNI";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
    $resultado->execute(array(":miDNI"=>$id, ":miApellido"=>$apellido, 
    ":miUsuario"=>$tipoUsuario));
```

Comment: Esta claro que no es recomendable ni acertado el planteamiento, pero para zanjar el tema y no quedarme con dudas, si forzosamente (siempre hablando de una bdd pequeña, como es el caso) deseara modificar desde php la PK mediante PDO, podría hacerlo? o mejor me olvido de esto ya que es imposible que se dé un caso así... ? gracias!

Comment: @Carlos, sí podrías hacerlo, por ejemplo, en el caso de que hayas asignado el DNI erróneamente. Pero el UPDATE debería diferente, algo así: `UPDATE usuario SET dni=:nuevoDNI, apellido=:miApellido, tipo_usuario=:miUsuario
                 WHERE dni=:miDNI` Si observas, hay un parámetro `:nuevoDNI` que sería el DNI corregido, mientras que `:miDNI` serviría para identificar el registro por el DNI antiguo. De todos modos sería un caso muy puntual.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás utilizando tanto en el WHERE como en el SET el mismo DNI (placeholder ":miDNI"), si quieres actualizar el DNI deberías utilizar el DNI actual en el WHERE (para buscar el registro), y el nuevo DNI en el SET. El placeholder ":DNI" no lo estabas utilizando.

Así debería quedar el código (solo cambié :miDNI por :DNI en `SET dni = :DNI,`).

```
$sql = "UPDATE usuario 
        SET dni = :DNI, 
            apellido = :miApellido, 
            tipo_usuario = :miUsuario 
        WHERE usuario.dni = :miDNI";   

$resultado = $base->prepare($sql);

$resultado->execute(array(":miDNI" => $id, ":miApellido" => $apellido, ":miUsuario" => $tipoUsuario, ":DNI" => $dni));
```

**¿Por qué no utilizar datos del modelo como clave primaria?**

En mi experiencia lo mejor es utilizar un campo autoincremental (Id) como llave primaria, y no un campo que forme parte del modelo de datos, las ventajas son:

- Si la tabla tiene relación con otras tablas, y por lo tanto la llave primaria es llave foranea en las demás tablas, facilita los joins ya que solo utilizas un campo para establecer la relación (al utilizar datos del modelo como llave primaria podrías necesitar una llave primaria compuesta por varios campos).
- Nunca necesitarías actualizar la llave primaria, en cambio si utilizaras datos del modelo como llave primaria podrías necesitar actualizarla, en caso de que la misma sea erronea.
- Al utilizar datos del modelo como llave primaria podría necesitar actualizar la misma, y por lo tanto tendrías que actualizar todas las tablas donde se utiliza ese campo como llave foranea.
- Se genera facilmente, y no te tienes que preocupar de validar que se inserte un valor duplicado (ya que se autoincrementa).
- Si la clave primaria se utiliza muchas veces como llave foranea, al ser simple requeriría menos espacio de almacenamiento que una llave compuesta.
- Si siempre utilizas el mismo nombre para el campo llave primaria (en todas las tablas) ej: Id (y para la llave foranea podría ser IdNombreTablaPK), te será facil recordar los campos para necesarios hacer los joins.

Una llave primaria no se debería actualizar, pero en tu caso podrías necesitar actualizar el DNI, porque por ejemplo el usario que lo ingreso lo cargo mal (le falto un numéro, intercambió dos números, tecleo un numero que no era, etc); y si ese DNI es utilizado en otras tablas como llave foranea (Foreign Key), tendrías que actualizarlo también en todas esas tablas, lo cual podría llegar a ser bastante trabajo.

El hecho de utilizar una llave primaria autoincremental, no implica que no tengas que validar que el DNI sea único, pero para ello puede utilizar una restricción de unicidad (unique constraint).